# XML conversion to JSON

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to return JSON, but the problem is that one of the values "001" is received as "1" at the client side in JSON.

Is there anything wrong I have done here? In Fiddler "TextView" shows the correct answer, but JSON does not.

Here is the code :

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
return new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ContainsJSON));
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you want to output JSON or XML? Also, give us more insight of the class being serialized to JSON.

Comment: I`m sorry if i`m not clear. I actually need "JSon" as end result. I`m converting Xml to JSon here. Problem is Converted JSon when i`m trying to return as above, the value which was "001" converted to "1" after when I recieve at client side.

Comment: can you show your code from the client side

Comment: @TanujWadhwa: I get correct value in fiddler in "Textview" as "001", but JSon shows "1". There is nothing handled at client side for this.

Answer (score 0):

The *GetBytes* method is overloaded. It behaves differently for string than for int.
I believe that invoking *ToString* on your ContainsJson object will yield the expected result.